# Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, mongoose-schema

So I was currently working on the Ticket system and wanted to try it out.

When I click on the Player report Button, I get a reply (in ephemeral) saying: "No data was found in the database" and in the logs, it gives me the following error

```
Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
```

This is the code:

```
const { 
    ButtonInteraction, 
    MessageEmbed, 
    MessageActionRow, 
    MessageButton 
} = require("discord.js");
const DB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/Ticket");
const { PARENTID, EVERYONEID } = require("../../Structures/config.json")

module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ButtonInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction){
        if(!interaction.isButton) return;
        const { guild, member, customId } = interaction;
        if(!["player", "bug", "other"].includes(customId)) return;

        const ID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;

        await guild.channels.create(`${customId + "-" + ID}`, {
            type: "GUILD_TEXT",
            parent: PARENTID,
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: member.id,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
                },
                {
                    id: EVERYONEID,
                    deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
                },
            ],
        }).then(async(channel) => {
            await DB.create({
                GuildID: guild.id,
                MemberID: member.id,
                TicketID: ID,
                ChannelID: channel.id,
                Closed: false,
                Locked: false,
                type: customId,
            });
            const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(
                `${guild.name} | Ticket: ${ID}`,
                guild.iconURL({dynamic: true})
            )
            .setDescription("Please wait patiently for a response from the Staff team. In the meanwhile, describe your issue in as much detail as possible."
            )
            .setFooter("The buttons below are Staff Only Buttons.");
    
            const Buttons = new MessageActionRow();
            Buttons.addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("close")
                .setLabel("Save & Close Ticket")
                .setStyle("PRIMARY")
                .setEmoji(""),
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("lock")
                .setLabel("Lock")
                .setStyle("SECONDARY")
                .setEmoji(""),
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("unlock")
                .setLabel("Unlock")
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setEmoji("")
            );
    
            channel.send({
                embeds: [Embed],
                components: [Buttons],
            });
            await channel
            .send({content: `${member} here is your ticket.`})
            .then((m) =>{
                setTimeout(() =>{
                    m.delete().catch(() => {});
                }, 1 * 5000);
            });
            interaction.reply({
                content: `${member} your ticket has been created: ${channel}`,
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        });
    },
};
```

I have been looking for the solution but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The reply you are getting (`"No data was found in the database"`) is stated nowhere in the code you have provided. That means that it is possible that two separate `interactionCreate` handlers are attempting to handle this button click, meaning you *have* already replied to the interaction. You have not provided the code for whatever other file is giving you the reply you mentioned, so we cannot really solve this issue for you. You just need to make sure that only one event handler replies to a given button, otherwise you will get the error you are getting.